# Java Boolean while loop - Evaluating a negation

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I am a beginner to Java, and although I thought I understood Boolean logic fairly well, I am being tripped up with this while loop:

```
boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "message");

    if (answer == null) finish();

    try {
        sales = Double.parseDouble(answer);
        if (sales<= 0) throw new NumberFormatException();
        else done = true;
    }
```

I am obviously reading this incorrectly because the code works and was taken directly from a book, but the way I would evaluate it is:

done = false,

while (done = true)

[code]

else done = true

So it would seem that this would create an infinite loop (or not start the while loop at all), but it doesn't. Can someone please help explain it?

Comment: `while(!done)` is equivalent to `while(done == false)`

Comment: You're missing a bit of code (at least the `catch` and/or `finally` clauses of the `try` satement and the closing brace for the `while` loop). The `while` loop encompasses the `try`.

Comment: An "!" mark infront of a boolean value reverse its original value. (e.g. !true = false)

Comment: Sorry Ted, this was just a snippet of the full code. There is a catch statement below this and a bracket on the while loop, not to mention some more methods. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's give the significant lines some line numbers:

```
while(!done) // (1)
{
    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "message");

    if (answer == null) finish();

    try
    {
        sales = Double.parseDouble(answer); // (2)
        if (sales<= 0) throw new NumberFormatException();
        else done = true; // (3)
    }
```

(1) is first executed, `done` is false, so `!done` is true, so the while loop starts.

(2) gets user input, let's suppose it is more than 0, it goes to (3).

(3) set `done` to true.

Now let's suppose the code execution has reached the end of the while loop. (1) is executed again. This time, `done` is true, so `!done` is false. If the condition in the while loop is false, the while loop stops iterating and the code directly below the while loop is executed.

> So it would seem that this would create an infinite loop

This wouldn't if you enter a number larger than or equal to 0. As I just said, a number larger than 0 will cause the while loop to stop. If you keep entering negative numbers, `done` will keep being false and so `!done` keeps being true. As a result, the while loop never stops.

Comment: Thank you so much! The concept of the While loop not iterating if the condition is false seems obvious now that you point it out, but for the life of me I could not figure it out. That completely explains it.

Comment: @anapollosun if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

You have misread the loop condition as `while (done = true)`, which is the opposite of the actual meaning (and uses the wrong operator). You don't compare booleans to booleans; in technical terms that is a silly action. You also don't assign a value to the loop variable in the conditional expression, because that leads to trouble, and isn't what you intended.

Let's walk through it.

`done` starts `false`. You need a boolean expression in the condition, `while (!done)`. The boolean expression must evaluate to `true` for the loop body to execute. `!done` => `!false` the first time. What is the value of `!false`? It's `true`! So the expression evaluates to `true` and the loop body executes.

Comment: Awesome explanation. I wasn't thinking about the returned true value: so then while(!done) = while(![true]) = while(false). And I also wasn't conscious of the fact that a while(false) condition will stop the loop.

Comment: `done` can change value. It's a variable. So `!done` evaluates to the negation of whatever value `done` has at the moment of evaluation. So when `done` is true, then `!done` is false. That `while(false)` stops the loop is the whole point of `while`. This is explained in the Java Tutorial.